# POST of decimal values to URL causes error in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, post

I am trying to `POST` some values to a URL using Codeigniter framework and I am running into a problem.  Everything works fine when the values in the post are whole numbers like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/myController/myMethod/1/2019/12345/
                                                   ------
```

However, when I need to post a decimal value to the URL it returns a `404 (Not Found)` error:

```
http://localhost:8080/myController/myMethod/1/2019/123.45/
                                                   ------
```

I don't know if this is relevant, but I recently changed the server to which this URL is doing the POST.  I don't remember experiencing this problem before changing the server, so perhaps there must be a problem with the new server.

Any idea why I can't post decimal values in my URL?

Comment: Encode the value before passing in URL and then decode.

Answer (score 1):

To be frank, I haven't used Codeigniter for almost 6 years.
But I know that a 404 error page means that your URL doesn't match any of the routes you have. If you use a wildcard `(:num)` in your routes, then try to replace it with a regular expression `([0-9\.]+)`. Because `(:num)` means only numbers from 0 to 9.

Answer (score -1):

Cause the [dot] will considered as a domain name.

For me, you can send data POST with body form-data so you don't have to worried about the URL, 
but if you still wanna send it from URL you can hashing it with character that not disturb the function of url. for example dont use `/`, `.`, etc